# Version of node for Sidekick

Tags: nativescript

I've just downloaded the latest Nativescript Sidekick. When I try to run it, I get the message that it is expecting:
"NodeJS >=8.0.0 <=10.5.0"

I'm using nvm, so I can switch node versions at will, but Sidekick appears to ignore this and pick up the latest (10.9.0 in my case). How does Sidekick detect the nodejs version? And how can I persuade otherwise???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After @GGarabedian confirmed that it worked with NVM for him, I played around a bit and discovered that Sidekick is looking for the NVM alias Stable.

So, by setting the alias to v8.11.0, Sidekick did work for me.

`nvm alias stable v8.11.0`

Answer (score 0):

I have tested NativeScript Sidekick with the Node Version Manager and it appears to detect the currently selected Node version correctly. Can you verify if you have installed and selected a NodeJS version between 8.0.0 and 10.5.0 by running the `node --version` command in the Command Prompt?

Also, my tests were conducted on a Windows machine and it would be good to know if you are running on the same or different OS.

Comment: Thanks, that pointed me in the right direction, see full answer above...